# Android Studio project structure VS build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add a maven repository to my project by adding it to build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://XXX/"
    }
}
```

It works fine when I build in the console. When I try to build it with Android Studio, the dependency that I use in that repository is not found.

When I add the repository to File > project structure > project > Default library Repository bam! it works.

What am I doing wrong? why do I have to duplicate the information? What is exactly the purpose of that configuration since it's already in build.gradle file?

Thank you

Comment: Which `repositories` do you modify?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @GenoChen. If you mean where is my shared code snipet, it is at the root of my build.gradle file from my android library. It's not the one inside buildscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Aghilas, i am not sure if it is issue with https or http. 
I am putting down what works for me. you can add 'maven()' in the block depending on that repo is required for buildscript functionality or for your app.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```